# Webpack HMR for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-hmr

I use `webpack` to bundle my nodejs code. As well known, we could use `webpack-dev-server` to build an environment for dev, so how about nodejs? I know `nodemon` can work, but it restart the whole project, I want a HMR way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this:

1. run `npm i --save-dev webpack-node-externals run-script-webpack-plugin webpack`
2. create a `webpack-hmr.config.js` file in the root directory of your application and put this:

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require('run-script-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (options, webpack) {
  return {
    ...options,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?100', options.entry],
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({
        allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?100'],
      }),
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...options.plugins,
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
        paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/],
      }),
      new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({ name: options.output.filename }),
    ],
  };
};
```

3. inside your `main.js`:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  <Your Express middleware and etc>
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => server.close());
  }
}
```

inspired by [Nest.js HMR](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload)

Comment: Could you please accept my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my slow reply. It seems to be interesting about those plugins, I will try and check it out later.