# Making HMR work with ESM & Node.JS & Webpack API

Tags: webpack, nestjs, webpack-dev-server

Sure, I've seen a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108338/webpack-hmr-for-node-js) that would clarify how to make that work with the webpack CLI.

But I'm trying to understand how to make it work when using webpack bundler directly through the API, and I was unable to find any way that is working for me. I tried to do it like:

```js
const compiler = webpack(await createWebpackConfig(entry))

  if (runDevServer) {
    compiler.watch(
      {
        aggregateTimeout: 1000,
      },
      (err, stats) => {
        process.stdout.write(`${stats.toString({ colors: true })}\n\n`)
      }
    )
```

And by having `['webpack/hot/poll?100', entry]` in the entry.

But that's not working because I have to run my HMR server somehow, because otherwise the app is unable to receive any updates, and I get the following error in my application instance.

```
[HMR] Update failed: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
```

My webpack config goes like:

```js
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const runDevServer = !!process.env.RUN_DEV_SERVER

export async function createWebpackConfig(entry: string): Promise<Configuration> {
  const packages = await findMonorepoPackages()

  const workspaces = packages.map(name => new RegExp(`^${name}(/.*)?$`))
  const allowedPackages = [...workspaces, /webpack\/hot\/poll\?100/]

  if (isProduction) {
    console.log('Making production build')
  }

  if (runDevServer) {
    console.log(`Going to run dev server of ${path.basename(entry, '.ts')}.mjs`)
  }
  const baseConfig: Configuration = {
    context: process.cwd(),
    watch: runDevServer,
    mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
      __filename: false,
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        module: /@nestjs\//,
      },
    ],
    ...(runDevServer
      ? {
          devServer: {
            static: './dist',
          },
        }
      : {}),
    stats: {
      colors: true,
    },
    performance: {
      hints: false,
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: false,
      splitChunks: {
        // include all types of chunks
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    },
    output: {
      globalObject: `typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this`,
      filename: '[name].mjs',
      path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
      library: {
        // do not specify a `name` here
        type: 'module',
      },
    },
    experiments: {
      outputModule: true,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /.tsx?$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'swc-loader',
            options: {
              minify: isProduction,
              jsc: {
                target: 'es2022',
                parser: {
                  syntax: 'typescript',
                  decorators: true,
                  dynamicImport: true,
                },
                transform: {
                  legacyDecorator: true,
                  decoratorMetadata: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new BannerPlugin({
        banner: "import 'source-map-support/register.js';",
        raw: true,
        entryOnly: false,
      }),
      new BannerPlugin({
        banner: '/* eslint-disable */\n//prettier-ignore',
        raw: true,
      }),
      ...(runDevServer
        ? [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
              paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/],
            }),
            new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({ name: `${path.basename(entry, '.ts')}.mjs`, autoRestart: false }),
          ]
        : []),
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.mjs'],
    },
    externals: [
      'perf_hooks',
      'fs/promises',
      ({ request, context }, callback) => {
        if (
          /^[^/.][a-zA-Z\-0-9./]+$/.test(request) &&
          !allowedPackages.some(regexp => regexp.test(request)) &&
          !includedInBundleExternals.includes(request)
        ) {
          return callback(null, `module ${request}`)
        }

        // Continue without externalizing the import
        return callback()
      },
    ],
  }

  return {
    ...baseConfig,
    entry: {
      [path.basename(entry, '.ts')]: runDevServer ? ['webpack/hot/poll?100', entry] : entry,
    },
  }
}
```

So the question is, how do I run the HMR server (or should I?) so the HMR updates are fetched correctly? I tried different ways like by setting different `entry` with `webpack-dev-server` and running the HMR server directly (`const server = new webpackDevServer({ hot: false, client: false }, compiler)`), but noone of that works. Am I looking at it the wrong way?

Other than that, I have quite the default Nest.JS application:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { NestFactory }          from '@nestjs/core'

import { QualificationsModule } from './qualifications.module'

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(QualificationsModule)
  await app.listen(3000)

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept()
    module.hot.dispose(() => app.close())
  }
}

bootstrap()
```